# Laravel yield parent section in child view

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Is there a way to yield a section in a child view declared in a parent view ?

if I yield('custom_code') in master view its working.

What I am doing wrong  ?

Master view

```
<html>
    @include('client.acccount')

    <h1>In Master</h1>

    @yield('bookInfo')
</html>
```

Child View

```
@extends('layouts.Master')

/*
    I also tried that

    @section('custom_code')
        @parent
    @endsection
*/

@section('bookInfo')
    <h1>In Child View</h1>
    @yield('custom_code')
@endsection
```

client.acccount file

```
@include('load_db_code')
```

load_db_code file

```
<?php
    $agent = Agent::find(Auth::id());
    $lang = Cache::get("lang");

    $temp = "";

    if (Session::has('demo'))
    {
        $temp = "temp_";
    }
?>

    @if($lang == 'fr')
        @if($agent->apparenceb2c->{$temp.'header_fr'} != "")
            @section('custom_code')
                {{ $agent->apparenceb2c->{$temp.'header_fr'} }}
            @endsection
        @endif
    @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `@yield` in a child view because of the direction that inheritance travels.

Instead of putting `custom_code` in a section, put it in a file based *view* (for example, `custom_code.blade.php`) and use:

```
@include('custom_code')
```

instead of

```
@yield('custom_code')
```

Comment: I get this error : View [custom_code] not found.
custom_code is not a view

Comment: So you can load that to a view called custom_view and then include it in your child view.

Comment: `Include` only works to include file based views, not to include blade sections. If `custom_code` is a *section* then you get the view not found error. if `custom_code` refers to an actual template, i.e.: `custom_code.blade.php` then you don't get the error.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```php
// parent.blade.php

@yield('footer', view('layouts.footer'))

// The footer is shown by default
```

#### Remove default parent code:

```php
// child.blade.php

@section('footer', '')
```

#### Extends parent code:

```php
// child.blade.php

@section('footer')

<p>I extend the footer</p>

@endsection
```